# How can I use a variable on my extended twig page (Symfony)?

Tags: php, symfony, variables, twig

I return data with my Controller.php to my twig template:

```
  return $this->render('list.html.twig', ['page' => $page]);
```

On my list.html.twig I can output my variable:

```
{{page.name}}
```

But I extend my base.html twig on my list.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
```

So when I want to output my variable on my base.html.twig:

```
{{page.name}}
```

Then I get the error message:

> Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime: "Variable "page" does not
>   exist." at /Users/work/project/templates/base.html.twig line 70

Comment: You need to add a service that provides this variable to the template, see https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html

Comment: Variable `page` should be known inside the extended template. See [here](https://twigfiddle.com/21wf0e) please make sure you are passing the variable correctly. Try a `{{ dump(_context) }}` in your main template

Comment: @jeroen I tested it like you suggested.   `globals:
        page: page`  But now I get the error message `Impossible to access an attribute ("slug") on a string variable ("page").`

Comment: @DarkBee With "main" template, do you mean base.html.twig?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Better to dump with `{{ dump(_context|keys) }}` though - This will allow you to see all defined variables

Comment: @DarkBee Oh yes, it is true, I found out that on the current page, the variable was not passed correctly. Exactly like you said. So variables usually are automatically passed to an extended twig

Comment: Yes, only macro's have another `scope` but extended templates and includes all use the same scope (defined in `_context`)

Comment: @Jarla I'd advise against using the direct variable in your extended template. The proper way would be to use the block scope. Otherwise you'll have to set the page variable on every single controller action that uses the extended template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your `base.html.twig` add a block like

```
{% block page %}{% endblock page %}
```

and on `list.html.twig` add `{% block page %}{{page.name}}{% endblock page %}`

So you could have a file like `base.html.twig`

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>{% block page %}{% endblock page %}
        <p>{% block content%}{% endblock content %}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

and a `list.html.twig` like

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block page %}{{ page.name }}{% endblock page %}
{% block content %}errything else for page here{% endblock content %}
```

and it'd be valid and would overwrite the page block for base.html.twig through inheritance.

Added a twigfiddle example
https://twigfiddle.com/d1hmo9

Comment: I do not understand unfortunately. I need to use the variable {{ page.name }} on base.html.twig, because it is used many times in a javascript block. On all my pages I want to extend base.html.twig, Otherwise I would need to write the javascipt part again and again on any page

Comment: With your example I am not free to use the {{ page.name }} variable anywhere on my base.html.twig

Comment: If you're extending `base.html.twig` in your `list.html.twig` like I posted above it will bubble up and fill in the block on the `base.html.twig`. try creating the `{% block page %}{% endblock page %}` on your `base.html.twig` and then add `{% block page %}{{ page.name }}{% endblock page %}` to your `list.html.twig`,

Just try it and see that it correctly populates.

Comment: The variable `page` should be known in the main template nonetheless. You don't need `block`'s for that

Comment: I still advise against using it directly outside the block scope, otherwise you'll have to include page on every single page.

Comment: I add to check, yes the variable should be defined in your template. But that doesn't make sens because if will throw an error if it is not defined in another controller action. But you can always do `if page is defined`. The block answer is the way to go.

Comment: No it's not.. You'd use a block to change the default behaviorof  a template. If the page name is always in the same spot e.g. `<head><title>{{ page_name|default('') }}</title></head>` it absolutely make no sense to use blocks and define it in every template that extends from the main template - Do note i'd wrap that code in a block if I ever need to adjust the default behavior and have to read out a `category`'s title instead of the `page`'s name